# Transformation of random variable implies equality almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I'm taking a first course in probability theory. I have not taken a measure theory course prior to this, and I'm struggling with some of the notions of equality.

For example, I've been given this question to formally prove:

Let $X$ and $Z$ be independent, with $X\sim N(0,1)$, and $P(Z=1) = P(Z=-1) = 1/2$. Let $Y=XZ$.

Prove that $P(|X|=|Y|)=1$.

Can I assume that the statement $Y=XZ$ implies that $P(Y=XZ)=1$? If so, taking the absolute value of both sides shows the necessary result, but I'm not sure how to show this formally - could anyone help out here?

In general, does equality of random variables mean that they're also equal a.s. and in prob., etc.? It would make sense because if they're equal everywhere then it has to be true that they're equal everywhere except on a set of measure $0$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Note that with probability one it is the case that
$$
|Y|=|XZ|=|X||Z|=|X|\times 1=|X|
$$

Formally, let $S=\{w\in \Omega\mid |Z(w)|=1\}$. Then $P(S=1)$ and for $w\in S$,
$$
|Y(\omega)|=|X(\omega)Z(\omega)|=|X(\omega)|Z(\omega)|=|X(\omega)|
$$
Hence $|Y|=|X|$ with probability one.

Comment: Yes, I agree, thanks, but my main question is more like "does equality of random variables mean that they're also equal a.s. and in prob., etc.?". It may seem obvious, but I just want to be sure I have the correct intuition about that.

Comment: Let $W, U$ be random variables (these are (measurable) maps $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$). Then $W=U$ with probability one/a.s. if the set $S=\{\omega\in \Omega \mid W(\omega)=U(\omega)\}$ is such that $P(S)=1$. In general a proposition $Q$ (some statement about $\Omega$) holds a.s. if the set of $w\in \Omega$ such that $Q$ holds has probability one.

Comment: Sorry if I'm beating a dead horse, but, in your opinion, does the statement $Y=XZ$ in the question (the actual question supplies no other information) imply that all of $Y, X, Z$ are random variables mapped from the same probability triple and that the set on which the equality is true has probability $1$ (and even equality on the sets with probability $0$), correct? Is just the equality of the random variables itself a stronger statement than saying they are equal almost surely?